# _TypeError was thrown building NotesListView(dirty) : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I don't know where this error is coming from
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iif15.png)

the debug console says the error is in the returning line and the return line return just returning a widget but the error is about string is null i don't from where this error is coming

this is notes_view.dart file

```
class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _notesService;
  String get userId => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Your Notes"),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(createOrUpdateNoteRoute);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            PopupMenuButton<MenuActions>(
              onSelected: (value) async {
                switch (value) {
                  case MenuActions.logout:
                    final shouldLogout = await showLogoutDialog(context);
                    if (shouldLogout) {
                      await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(loginRoute, (_) => false);
                    }
                    break;
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (context) {
                return const [
                  PopupMenuItem<MenuActions>(
                      value: MenuActions.logout, child: Text("Log out")),
                ];
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _notesService.allNotes(ownerUserId: userId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
              case ConnectionState.active:
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final allNotes = snapshot.data as Iterable<CloudNote>;
                  return NotesListView(
                    notes: allNotes,
                    onDeleteNote: (note) async {
                      await _notesService.deleteNote(
                          documentId: note.documentId);
                      print(note.documentId);
                    },
                    onTap: (note) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                        createOrUpdateNoteRoute,
                        arguments: note,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              default:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

this is notes_list_view.dart file

```
typedef NoteCallback = void Function(CloudNote note);

class NotesListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Iterable<CloudNote> notes;
  final NoteCallback onDeleteNote;
  final NoteCallback onTap;

  const NotesListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.notes,
    required this.onDeleteNote,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: notes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final note = notes.elementAt(index);
        return ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            onTap(note);
          },
          textColor: Colors.black87,
          title: Text(
            note.text,
            maxLines: 1,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.delete,
              color: Colors.red[200],
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              final shouldDelete = await deleteDialog(context);
              if (shouldDelete) {
                onDeleteNote(note);
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is the firebase_cloud_storage.dart file

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/cloud/cloud_note.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/cloud/cloud_storage_constants.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/cloud/cloud_storage_exceptions.dart';

class FirebaseCloudStorage {
  final notes = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');

  Future<void> deleteNote({required String documentId}) async {
    try {
      await notes.doc(documentId).delete();
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNoteException();
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateNote({
    required String documentId,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    try {
      await notes.doc(documentId).update({textFieldName: text});
    } catch (_) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNotesException();
    }
  }

  Stream<Iterable<CloudNote>> allNotes({required String ownerUserId}) {
    return notes.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
        .map((doc) => CloudNote.fromSnapshot(doc))
        .where((note) => note.ownerUserId == ownerUserId));
  }

  Future<Iterable<CloudNote>> getNotes({required String ownerUserId}) async {
    try {
      return await notes
          .where(ownerUserIdFieldName, isEqualTo: ownerUserId)
          .get()
          .then(
            (value) => value.docs.map((doc) => CloudNote.fromSnapshot(doc)),
          );
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotGetAllNotesException();
    }
  }

  Future<CloudNote> createNewNote({required String ownerUserId}) async {
    final document = await notes.add({
      ownerUserIdFieldName: ownerUserId,
      textFieldName: '',
    });
    final fetchedNote = await document.get();
    return CloudNote(
      documentId: fetchedNote.id,
      ownerUserId: ownerUserId,
      text: '',
    );
  }

  static final FirebaseCloudStorage _shared =
      FirebaseCloudStorage._sharedInstance();
  FirebaseCloudStorage._sharedInstance();
  factory FirebaseCloudStorage() => _shared;
}
```

```
@immutable
class CloudNote {
  final String documentId;
  final String ownerUserId;
  final String text;

  const CloudNote({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.ownerUserId,
    required this.text,
  });

  CloudNote.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        ownerUserId = snapshot.data()[ownerUserIdFieldName],
        text = snapshot.data()[textFieldName] as String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will like to accept `null` data while reading map, try

```dart
 text = snapshot.data()[textFieldName] ?? "got null value";
```

```dart
CloudNote.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
    : documentId = snapshot.id,
      ownerUserId = snapshot.data()[ownerUserIdFieldName] ?? "default value",
      text = snapshot.data()[textFieldName] ?? "Default value";
```

Comment: Also can be handled on Text widget like `title: Text("${note.text}"),`